# What is "openssl binaries" and "openssl development package"?

Tags: compiling, openssl

> Build it using general C development environment with bash, gcc (3 or
>   4 series), make, etc on a linux machine.
>
> Building pre-requirements are:
>
> **
>
> ```
> 1. openssl binaries;
> 2. openssl development package with include files (on debian package libssl-dev);
> ```
>
> **

Answer (score 47):

OpenSSL binaries are provided by package `openssl`. It "contains the openssl binary and related tools" (from openssl package description).

OpenSSL development package is `libssl-dev`. "SSL development libraries, header files and documentation" (from libssl-dev package description).