# Completely remove openssl dev version

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, openssl, purge, removing

I installed openssl dev version from github. However, I now wish to remove it to install openssl from the official repos.

I tried to remove it using `sudo apt-get remove --purge openssl` but it's still available to me through terminal.

```
goelakash@goelakash-acer:~/softwares$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0-pre3-dev  xx XXX xxxx
```

How do I get rid of the this version?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/318775/what-is-openssl-binaries-and-openssl-development-package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

Comment: There is no uninstall rule for openssl in the git repo.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the executable by first finding where the current version of openssl was residing:

```
whereis openssl
```

and then reinstalling openssl

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

Comment: How did you remove the paths returned by `whereas openssl`? Just using `rm -rf`?

Answer (score -1):

Just type this command on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove openssl
```

Comment: I haven't tried that, because I'm not into losing my system due to someone's unwise post on this platform, but most likely this is going to render your system useless, so don't do it! For example, in my system this says "The following packages will be REMOVED" and then it lists half of the core most important system packages.

Comment: I actually removed a certain openssl version like that and then reinstalled all of the packages that were removed. Note, that they seem to depend on exactly the version supplied, so you'll probably have to reinstall it to have them anyway.